# ensure that new faucet fits the pipe

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I need to purchase a new `faucet` for kitchen. The house is pretty old, built in 1994, so I'd like to make sure that the new `faucet` will fit in pipes exactly. What do I have to pay attention at when buying a faucet? Are they pretty much standard these days?

Attached is the faucet's underneath picture

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: usually when you purchase a faucet you need to separately buy the water supply tubes ( They do that so you can get the correct type and length )  You might want to pull one of the old tubes and take it to the store with you, or at least take a good look and measure the length.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added a picture of my faucet's pipes. So the water supply tubes you're talking about are copper ones (in my case), and I have to ensure that the new faucet will fit in those, correct?

Comment: right either make sure the new faucet fits the tubes (be very careful if you need to bend them to fit.)  Alternately buy new tubes . Braided stainless make install much easier..

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is a pretty old house....Really, mine was built in 1975, so it must be ancient! But your faucet should be pretty standard, however, the valves could be any of a few standard sizes. You would need to make sure you get the proper hoses to attach the faucet to the water valve.